# Sending data to parse.com and update angular $scope

Tags: javascript, angularjs, function, parse-platform, ionic-framework

I am sending data to a Class at parse.com, I would like to run this function and update the `$scope` without having to reload the view.

To create a `Programme` running the function below works fine, however it sometimes does not update the view following creating a new programme and it requires a page refresh (when the whole function is called as seen at the bottom - `getProgrammes();`

```
getProgrammes = function() {
$ionicLoading.show();

var programmesArray = [];
var QueryProgramme = Parse.Object.extend("Programme");
var query = new Parse.Query(QueryProgramme);

query.equalTo("userId", userId);
query.find({
success: function(results) {
  for(var i=0; i < results.length; i++) {
    var object = results[i];

    var programmeData = { title : object.get('programmeTitle'), 
                          id : object.id,
                          exercises : object.get('exerciseData')
                        };

    programmesArray.push(programmeData);
  }

  $scope.programmes = programmesArray;
  $scope.$apply();
  $ionicLoading.hide();
   },
   error: function(error) {
   alert('You do not have any Programmes - please create one');
   }
 })
};

getProgrammes();
```

I think I may be hacking this by using `$scope.apply()` - therefore making it unreliable. Assistance on the correct function to use in order to automatically update `$scope` would be great.

Comment: You shouldn't need to call $scope.$apply(). You should just be able to set the property on $scope. Perhaps provide a js fiddle demonstrating the problem

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've been using a library found here:

https://github.com/brandid/parse-angular-patch

Essentially I just reference the parse-angular.js file, and then include the dependency in my app, e.g.:

```
angular.module('app', [
  'parse-angular',
]);
```

Then I just use Parse queries anytime I like and they participate correctly with `$scope` and `$apply`. The library just does some simple wrapping on the Parse methods to make the async calls obey the rules of angular.

Comment: I've looked at this previously and found I couldn't follow the documentation on it (my lack of experience) however I will look again.

Comment: The documentation is overly complicated, that's why I explained it with two simple steps, just add the JS file and add the references to your app declaration, nothing else is needed for basic functionality

Comment: I'm being a real dumbass or something, where is the JS file I need? Reference to components/ in index.js but is that some bower magic?

Comment: Nope still can't figure out what I should use as the JS file?

Comment: Sorry, the simple version I use is found here: https://github.com/brandid/parse-angular-patch

Comment: Perfect - I can follow this :)

Comment: @Taylorsuk thanks for the edit suggestion, sorry it got rejected. I've made the change manually.