# parse-angular-patch not working anymore

Tags: angularjs, parse-platform, parse-server

I was happily using parse-angular-patch. As you all know parse.com is shutting down in few months. In order to use parse SDK with parse open source server, you need to upgrade the javascript SDK version to the latest version(1.9.2).

I tried to upgrade the parse javascript version to 1.9.2 today and my application stopped working. I got the following error.

```
parse-angular.js:62 Uncaught TypeError: 
Cannot read property 'prototype' of undefined(anonymous function) 
@ parse-angular.js:62(anonymous function) 
@ parse-angular.js:60e 
@  angular.js:4142(anonymous function) 
@ angular.js:4065s 
@ angular.js:323ab  
@ angular.js:4064d 
@ angular.js:1447tc 
@ angular.js:1470Jd 
@ angular.js:1415(anonymous function) 
@ angular.js:26063j 
@ jquery.js:3094fireWith 
@ jquery.js:3206ready 
@ jquery.js:3412I 
@ jquery.js:3428
```

Here is my app declaration.

```
angular.module('app',[
    ...
    'parse-angular',
    'parse-angular.enhance',
    ...
])
```

I am using angular 1.3.14. Have any one tried to migrate existing angular v1 code using parse js sdk to parse server infrastructure and succeeded. any help would be highly appreciated in order to fix the error above.

Comment: I got the idea of using parse-angular from this question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28005281/sending-data-to-parse-com-and-update-angular-scope/28007376#28007376

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just encountered the same issue today and found this:

https://github.com/JeremyPlease/parse-angular-patch

Which seems to work with the new parse SDK.